# How to use php to show hover/selected class on pages when the Nav bar (not created with a ul) is in a separate include file?

Tags: php, navigation, include

I have a php template set up where the top and bottom common information is in separate include files. How do I make it so that the hovered a class shows up on each page when it's the current page? (The effect for each nav bar element is different- it's a small icon to the left of the words.)
Thanks!

See code below:

```
<nav>
         <div class="page">
          <a href="themes.php" class="themes">Themes</a>
            <a href="custom-gifts.php" class="custom-gifts">Custom Gifts</a>
            <a href="about-us.php" class="about-us">About Us</a>
            <a href="testimonials.php" class="testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            <a href="contact-us.php" class="contact-us">Contact Us</a>
         </div>
         </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {top:0px; text-align:right; margin:0px auto;}
nav a {margin: 12px 10px 10px 20px;}
a.themes {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 24px;
    background: url(../images/themes-sprint.png) no-repeat left 0px;
    height:23px;
}
a.themes:hover { background-position: left -23px; }


a.custom-gifts {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background: url(../images/custom-gifts-sprint.png) no-repeat left 0px;
}
a.custom-gifts:hover { background-position: left -22px; }

a.about-us {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background: url(../images/about-us-sprint.png) no-repeat left 0px;
}
a.about-us:hover { background-position: left -22px; }

a.testimonials {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background: url(../images/testimonials-sprint.png) no-repeat left 0px;
}
a.testimonials:hover { background-position: left -22px; }

a.contact-us {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background: url(../images/contact-us-sprint.png) no-repeat left 0px;
}
a.contact-us:hover { background-position: left -22px; }
```

(The reason the nav bar is set up without lists and with separate sprint images is because I've designed the site to be responsive, and in the mobile version the navigation pieces appear one atop the other instead of next to each other.)

Comment: PHP has absolutely nothing to do with this. PHP runs on the server and cannot possibly see what the mouse is doing on the client. At best you can use PHP to set a class on the "current" element, which your css can look for, e.g. `.current:hover { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the suggestion. Can you explain how I'd go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got you right. Try this:

```
    <? $f=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>

    <div class="page">
        <a href="themes.php" class="themes<?=($f=='themes.php'?' on':'')?>">Themes</a>
        <a href="custom-gifts.php" class="custom-gifts<?=($f=='themes.php'?' on':'')?>">Custom Gifts</a>
        <a href="about-us.php" class="about-us<?=($f=='about-us.php'?' on':'')?>">About Us</a>
        <a href="testimonials.php" class="testimonials<?=($f=='testimonials.php'?' on':'')?>">Testimonials</a>
        <a href="contact-us.php" class="contact-us<?=($f=='contact-us.php'?' on':'')?>">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
```

The 1st line is loading the name of the current file into the variable `$f`. In the following lines, we check `$f`against the filename, and if they are equal output `on` within the `class`-Attribute of the `<a>`-tag, e.g. `class="contact-us on"`.

Now add a CSS for `.on`and you have it.

Comment: Another question expanding on this concept- how can I use this method so that all pages in a certain directory have the on class? For example, let's say I'd want all pages in the /theme directory to have the theme on class? Can I specify the php to find the directory name as the variable instead of an individual page name?

Comment: @user2069532: please explain in greater detail: do you want the class for all `<a>...</a>` in say, `index.php` with `href` containing `/theme`, e.g. `<a href="theme/apage.php">a page</a>`?